# How to bind treeview with data from object ( WPF XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I am trying to create treeview in WPF with data from my list, but i am not able to do so.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string studentname { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}

List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();
```

Students object contains following data

```
department      Student     Code
A               John        1
B               Tonny       2
C               Jai         3
A               Rocky       4
C               Mickey      5
A               Donald      6
```

I want this to be represented in Treeview like this:

```
+ A
  John 1
  Rocky 4
  Donald 6
+ B
  Tonny 2
+ C
  Jai 3
  Mickey 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Tree Views are hierarchical, based on your object you need to view the visual TREE in a different way, your left column of students repeats the department, it would be better to view the departments have students to get the desired output on the tree. This is not the best or the only way to do this but demonstrates the structure an building blocks required.

Create a new WPF project

In MainWindow.xaml

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfTestTreeView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestTreeView"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="tvDepts">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <!-- Top level template -->
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Department}" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <!-- Child node template -->
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Student}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Name: " FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" Code: " FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfTestTreeView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private ObservableCollection<Department> _departments;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // This is a long winded way but it shows the mechanics of the collections 

            _departments = new ObservableCollection<Department>();
            //Create New Depaertment and Student objects
            Department d1 = new Department("A");
            Student s1 = new Student("John","1");
            // Add the Student to the Department Student List
            d1.Students.Add(s1);
            Student s2 = new Student("Rocky", "4");
            // Add the Student to the Department Student List
            d1.Students.Add(s2);
            Student s3 = new Student("Donald", "6");
            // Add the Student to the Department Student List
            d1.Students.Add(s3);
            // Add the Department to The Departments List
            Departments.Add(d1);

            Department d2 = new Department("B");
            Student s4 = new Student("Tony", "2");
            d2.Students.Add(s4);
            Departments.Add(d2);

            Department d3 = new Department("C");
            Student s5 = new Student("Jai", "3");
            d3.Students.Add(s5);
            Student s6 = new Student("Mickey", "5");
            d3.Students.Add(s6);
            Departments.Add(d3);

            // set itemsource on the treeview
            tvDepts.DataContext = Departments;
            tvDepts.ItemsSource = Departments;

        }

        public ObservableCollection<Department> Departments
        {
            get { return _departments; }
            set { _departments = value; }
        }
    }

    // Department Class Holds a Collection of Students
    public class Department
    {

        private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;

        public Department(string name)
        {
            _students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Collection Of Student in the Department
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
        {
            get { return _students; }
            set { _students = value; }
        }
    }
// Student Class
    public class Student
    {
        public Student(string name, string code)
        {
            StudentName = name;
            Code = code;
        }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you get an understanding :)